# Error while fetching values from list of dictionaries inside a dictionary in a tuple

Tags: python, django

Edit - Made changes to the code from where I'm receiving the jsondata and converting it into a dictionary.
(Sorry for the inconvenience and confusion caused)

I need to fetch values from product_name which is a key in the list of dictionaries inside a dictionary.

```py
products = ([{'product_id': 'WVXNR', 
'product_name': 'BASUNDI 200 ML', 
'product_description': 'A traditional taste of sweetened condensed milk with rich creamy flavor, can be served warm or chilled.', 
'product_images': '/images/productImages/Basundi_lH9o5wD.png',
'product_price': 80.0, 
'gst': 0, 
'product_status': None, 
'discount': None, 
'rating': None, 
'product_quantity': 1, 
'get_product_total': 80.0, 
'get_product_total_gst': 0.0}, 
{'product_id': 'MEADN', 
'product_name': 'MASALA MILK', 
'product_description': 'Blended with dry fruit and saffron is rich in vitamins and minerals, this healthy and nutritious milk is an all-time favorite!!', 
'product_images': '/images/productImages/masala_milk_BlypKDx.png',
'product_price': 190.0, 
'gst': 0, 
'product_status': None, 
'discount': None, 
'rating': None, 
'product_quantity': 1, 
'get_product_total': 190.0, 
'get_product_total_gst': 0.0
}],)
```

What I've tried
Assuming `products` is a variable containing all the data

```
product_name = [x for x in products['product_name']]
```

Correction above

Doing this would give me

```py
tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

What I need

```py
product_name = ['BASUNDI 200 ML', 'MASALA MILK']
```

Comment: Can you give an explicit example for the values of `product_data` and `product_price`?

Comment: @Yokhen I've edited the question with what I actually need, maybe you'll get a better idea.

Comment: The code you've provided has first a list containing one dictionary and then another dictionary. Is this correct? Or do you have one list containing all of the dictionaries you've provided?

Comment: @chemicalwill this is dictionary converted from a json response, the data pasted/provided is correct.

Comment: It's unclear if everything you've provided would be contained within the same variable or not. Is the top list separate from the bottom dictionary?

Comment: @chemicalwill sorry for the confusion but it's all in the same variable.

Comment: Please provide the assignment statement for `product_data`, i.e. `product_data = `. We're just guessing without this information.

Comment: I've rolled back as the OP says it's all the same variable. OP you really need to fix your data if you want us to help

Comment: @MichaelRuth updated the question and made changes to how I'm collecting and converting the data from response.

Comment: @MichaelRuth made changes to the question and how data is collected

Comment: Why does this code wrap the  `list` in a `tuple`? It seems superfluous.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that

```py
products = product_data['products']
```

results in

```
[{'product_id': 'NNPTA', 'product_name': 'CHASS 200 ML', 'product_description': 'The secret recipe of butter milk from Punjab Sind Foods is a refresher any time! an excellent source of probiotics and a must have with every meal for better digestion.', 'product_images': '/images/productImages/Masala_Chass_yGg9K92.png', 'product_price': 28.0, 'gst': 0, 'product_status': None, 'discount': None, 'rating': None, 'product_quantity': 2, 'get_product_total': 56.0, 'get_product_total_gst': 0.0}, {'product_id': 'HZCNM', 'product_name': 'FRESH MILK 1 LTR', 'product_description': 'Our milk is free of chemical, pesticides and preservatives. We are committed to provide hygienic and healthy milk every time you order from us.', 'product_images': '/images/productImages/Fresh_milk_IL.png', 'product_price': 62.0, 'gst': 0, 'product_status': None, 'discount': None, 'rating': None, 'product_quantity': 1, 'get_product_total': 62.0, 'get_product_total_gst': 0.0}]
```

Then what you are looking for can be obtained with:

```py
product_names = [x['product_name'] for x in products]
```

Comment: Hey, thanks but this would give me ```list indices must be integers or slices, not str``` as well for some reason at  ```product_name = [x['product_name'] for x in products] ```

Comment: I tested it myself on python, if the input I assumed is correct, the generator evaluates correctly with the output you desire. If the input I assumed is not correct, then please help me out here with a good test case.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the edit. Watch the stray comma at the end of your data (this creates a tuple, rather than a list).

```
products = ([{'product_id': 'WVXNR',
'product_name': 'BASUNDI 200 ML',
'product_description': 'A traditional taste of sweetened condensed milk with rich creamy flavor, can be served warm or chilled.',
'product_images': '/images/productImages/Basundi_lH9o5wD.png',
'product_price': 80.0,
'gst': 0,
'product_status': None,
'discount': None,
'rating': None,
'product_quantity': 1,
'get_product_total': 80.0,
'get_product_total_gst': 0.0},
{'product_id': 'MEADN',
'product_name': 'MASALA MILK',
'product_description': 'Blended with dry fruit and saffron is rich in vitamins and minerals, this healthy and nutritious milk is an all-time favorite!!',
'product_images': '/images/productImages/masala_milk_BlypKDx.png',
'product_price': 190.0,
'gst': 0,
'product_status': None,
'discount': None,
'rating': None,
'product_quantity': 1,
'get_product_total': 190.0,
'get_product_total_gst': 0.0
}])
```

The following list comprehension should return what you need now.

```
product_names = [d['product_name'] for d in products]
print(product_names)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. However I've made changes to the question and data, can you please check again?

Comment: @coder updated my answer. Should work with your data (provided you remove the comma at the end)

Comment: I think its the comma at the that's creating the problem and now I get '''list indices must be integers or slices, not str''', I tried doing ```products = products[0]``` thinking it would give me the *list* (first and only) inside the tuple but it returned a tuple with the first dictionary minus the list viz. ```({data})```. But ```product_name ``` would work fine giving me ['BASUNDI 200 ML'].

Comment: @coder can you update your question with your current code? Since I am getting what you expect to get in the question, I think there is something wrong on your end.

Answer (score 0):

Since product_data is a list which is a iterable, you can use map function with lambda function that extracts from the dict:

```
product_names = list(map(lambda product: product["product_name"], product_data))
```